# How to position a partial view in a page when load dynamically after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

i am new in mvc so like to ask 2 noob questions and those are

1) how to load partial view dynamically after postback. suppose i have a button in my main view and when user will click then i want to load a partial view dynamically after postback. i know how to load partial view dynamically using jquery but i want to know how can i load partial view after postback in main view without using jquery.

2) when we load any view dynamically by jquery then very easily we can capture the view rendered html and set or position that html in any where in my main view but i want to know how could i position or adding partial view html after postback. is it at all possible without using jquery?

in asp.net webform we can load user control dynamically after postback and also we can add that usercontrol any where in page without using jquery. the same kind of flexibility is there in mvc or is it restricted.

please give answer point wise with example or sample code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your first question you can use different techniques, here is a sample

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
   ViewBag.ShowPartial = true;
   return View();
}
```

in the view

```
@if (ViewBag.ShowPartial)
{
    Html.Partial("_MyPartial");
}
```

for second question i suggest you read a little more about asp.net mvc, and postback means nothing in asp.net mvc, it is post request and get request so on, and you can easily add what ever you want to the view

one other sample

in the view

```
@if (Request.RequestType == "Post")
{
     // do what ever you want
}
```